# Using system.linq.lookup values for dropdownfor mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, collections, lambda, html.dropdownlistfor

In MVC 4 I am using razor to get items from collection and assign it to a var. The var is of type

```
{System.Linq.Lookup<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>.Grouping}
```

This is my code

```
 var ChairList = Model.Interviewers.Where(d => d.LocKey == Convert.ToString(location.LocationKey) && d.IsChair && d.Date == date.Date).GroupBy(x => new { x.FullDetails, x.InterviewerId, x.Preference }).ToList();
```

And how it looks in watch:

```
-       ChairList   Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>>
-       [0] {System.Linq.Lookup<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>.Grouping} System.Linq.IGrouping<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer> {System.Linq.Lookup<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>.Grouping}
+       [System.Linq.Lookup<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>.Grouping] {System.Linq.Lookup<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>.Grouping} System.Linq.Lookup<<>f__AnonymousType0<string,System.Guid,string>,IMEModels.InterviewManagement.Interviewer>.Grouping
-       Key { FullDetails = "TEST - Richard Jackson - (80020937)", InterviewerId = {ff1efad7-7176-4fab-a1bb-30f6656c8880}, Preference = "Available" }   <Anonymous Type>
        FullDetails "TEST - Richard Jackson - (80020937)"   string
+       InterviewerId   {ff1efad7-7176-4fab-a1bb-30f6656c8880}  System.Guid
        Preference  "Available" string
+       Raw View
```

I want to use this for a dropdownfor but it doesn't recognise the key and value that I am giving for it:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[location.InterviewDates.IndexOf(date)].ChairId, new SelectList(ChairList, "InterviewerId", "FullDetails"))
```

Can someone help me with this piece of code? It's possible that there is an easier way of doing this that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

**For view**

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[location.InterviewDates.IndexOf(date)].ChairId,, ViewData["ReturnList"] as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**For Code**     (Return as viewData)

```
 public SelectList ReturnList(Guid UID) {
            var ChairList = Model.Interviewers.Where(d => d.LocKey == Convert.ToString(location.LocationKey) && d.IsChair && d.Date == date.Date).GroupBy(x => new { x.FullDetails, x.InterviewerId, x.Preference }).ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> selectItems = ChairList.Select(s => new SelectListItem() {
                Text =FullDetails,
                Value = InterviewerId.ToString(),
                Selected =  false
            }
          ).ToList();
            selectItems.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() {
                Text = " --Select -- ",
                Value = null,
                Selected = false
            });
            SelectList selectList = new SelectList(selectItems, "Value", "Text");
            return selectList;
        }
```